# What's the difference between measurement resolution and digits per second in time measuring devices

Tags: measurement, frequency-measurement, time, units

In time/frequency counters/analyzers in technical specifications you can almost always find resolution and digits per second values next to each other. What is the difference?

Comment: Give an example. "Digits per second" doesn't sound right.

Comment: Digits has nothing to do with resolution, resolution does.

Comment: @Transistor https://pendulum.se/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/pendulum-cnt-90_timer-counter-analyzer.pdf it s confusing to me too

Comment: @Trevor Huh... what do you know? There is a thing called "Digits/second"... -looks up digits per second on Google-... AH HA! You're talking about "Symbols per second" or "baud/sample rate".

Comment: @KingDuken well duh..but 12 digits/s on a 250K measurements per second meter does not really fit does it.

Comment: @Trevor that doesn't even make sense physically. I wouldn't know whether you can even theoretically build an atomic clock that achieves 12 digits of accuracy in frequency, so it really can't be a frequency measurement. So, even if it displays 12 digits of a frequency, those can impossibly be of significance, as the reference time can't be accurate enough.

Comment: @MarcusMüller yup...

Comment: @MarcusMüller It seems that accuracy isn't an issue (here). A wild guess: FFT bin interpolation might be used in Trevor's example instrument?

Comment: @glen_geek nope, in any case of a spectral estimator (like the FFT), you'd get *variance* in your estimation – so, no, there's no free lunch, and you can't get 12 significant digits with a clock source only exact to (at most, with the most expensive add-on) 9 digits.

Comment: @Transistor an example I have in mind would be http://www.carmelinst.com/Products/TIAs/BI201.aspx

Comment: @Luke: Thanks. I haven't a clue either. Contact them and let us know what they say.

Comment: @Transistor the problem is that everybody use that unit, not only Carmel. https://www.keysight.com/en/pd-1000001409%3Aepsg%3Apro-pn-5371A/frequency-and-time-interval-analyzer?nid=-536902484.536880766&cc=PL&lc=eng
http://www.thinksrs.com/products/SR620.htm

They don't reply anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carmel Instruments [products](http://www.carmelinst.com/Products.aspx) page for time interval analyzers / frequency counters explains it as follows:

> **Freq. Resolution** - The resolution for Frequency Average and Period Average functions is dependent on the single-shot time resolution and the duration of the measurement (effective gate time). **It is easier to specify it as a number of digits per second.** For example, 12 digits/s means that you will get 12 digits of frequency resolution with a 1 second gate time, or 9 digits in 1 millisecond. If the signal input is 1 MHz, 9 digits of resolution translates to 0.001 Hz resolution.

So some of the comments were on the right track. I note that this specification gives no indication of accuracy and, as posted in the comments.

Back to your question:

> What's the difference between measurement resolution and digits per second in time measurement devices?

According to Carmel there isn't a difference other than it is easier to relate meter resolution to time interval when using digits per second.

Comment: You're right. I must have missed that information while reading their page. Thank you very much.